# sending contact responses to email

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have the following code:

```js
const form = document.forms.myform;
form.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries())

  // for test
  console.clear()
  console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data))

  let validationOK = true
  for (let entrie in data) {
    if (!form[entrie].checkValidity()) {
      validationOK = false
      form[entrie].classList.add('shakingErr')
      setTimeout(() => {
        form[entrie].classList.remove('shakingErr')
      }, 820)
    }
  }
  if (validationOK) {
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: data,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        window.location = "thankyou.html"
      })
  }
}



//Contact Form Error Animation 
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var isValid = true;
  this.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach(function(f) {
    if (!f.checkValidity()) {
      isValid = false;
      f.style.borderColor = "red";
      f.style.animation = "shake 0.82s forwards";
      setTimeout(function() {
        f.style.animation = "unset";
      }, 820);
    } else {
      f.style.borderColor = "initial";
    }
  })
  if (!isValid) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.82s forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="https://formspree.io/f/xrgjbqpq" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This code is not sending the responses to my email and I'm not sure where the error is in the JS logic. Basically, it should send the contact responses to the email or basically execute the `action` I have in the HTML. I use Formspree for sending contact responses to my email but I do not know where the error is in the JS file. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this task?

Basically I did some changes to my JS code and before it worked fine where it sent responses to the email but now I do not know what happened. This was the previous JS file which **sent the responses to the email:**

```
var form = document.getElementById("my-form");

async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData(event.target);
  fetch(event.target.action, {
    method: form.method,
    body: data,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).finally(() => {
    window.location = "thankyou.html";
  });
}
myform.firstname.oninvalid = badEntrie
myform.lastname.oninvalid = badEntrie
myform.email.oninvalid = badEntrie
myform.subject.oninvalid = badEntrie

function badEntrie({ target }) {
  target.classList.add('shakingErr')
  setTimeout(() => { target.classList.remove('shakingErr') }, 820)
}
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
```

Comment: Are the validation checks passing?

Comment: yes the validation checks pass but it does not send the responses to the email, or in other words, the `action` attribute in html never gets executed

Comment: I'm getting, `can't send an empty form`, from the response.
The body is `[object Object]`.

Comment: So when you enter the information in the contact form, the responses don't get sent to my email. That is the only issue.

Comment: Yep, because the requests fail. Check this part `let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries())`.

Comment: What should I replace it with? Or should I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to JSON.stringify() the data in the fetch request.

```js
const form = document.forms.myform;
form.onsubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries())
  
  console.log(data)

  let validationOK = true
  for (let entrie in data) {
    if (!form[entrie].checkValidity()) {
      validationOK = false
      form[entrie].classList.add('shakingErr')
      setTimeout(() => {
        form[entrie].classList.remove('shakingErr')
      }, 820)
    }
  }
  if (validationOK) {
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: form.method,
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        window.location = "thankyou.html"
      })
  }
}



//Contact Form Error Animation 
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var isValid = true;
  this.querySelectorAll('input, textarea').forEach(function(f) {
    if (!f.checkValidity()) {
      isValid = false;
      f.style.borderColor = "red";
      f.style.animation = "shake 0.82s forwards";
      setTimeout(function() {
        f.style.animation = "unset";
      }, 820);
    } else {
      f.style.borderColor = "initial";
    }
  })
  if (!isValid) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.82s forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2><br/>Get In Touch</h2>
        </div>
        <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="https://formspree.io/f/xrgjbqpq" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```